# AIX/UNIX: module has an invalid magic number

Tags: shared-libraries, aix, magic-numbers

On AIX, I am executing a script. In this script,  it tries to load a 64 bit shared object lib ( .so file) . It fails to do so by giving the following error:

The module has an invalid magic number.

If I type "prtconf" it shows me that the system is 64 bit.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I think more details are probably needed to answer this.  It could be that you have multiple copies of the shared lib file on the system and it's loading the one you don't expect. It does sound like a 32/64-bit incompatibility issue, though.  Where did the .so come from?  How do you know it's 64-bit?  Are you sure whatever you're doing in your script is 64-bit?